# Is it possible to scrape data from an interactive graph?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Is there an R code I could use to extract the data from 'https://www.politico.eu/europe-poll-of-polls/austria/' specifically for the "Freedom Party of Austria"?

Answer (score 4):

The graph is constructed from data transmitted to your browser in json format from an XHR call. Using developer tools in your browser, you can find the url of the json and read it directly.

The url you need is:

```r
url <- "https://www.politico.eu/wp-json/politico/v1/poll-of-polls/AT-parliament"
```

You get a wealth of data from this json, including several tables that might be of interest. They can be put in an R list with:

```
all_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
```

The data you want can be extracted and put into a tidy data frame like this:

```
df <- all_data$trends$kalman
df <- cbind(df[1], df$parties)
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   date       name   value
#>   <date>     <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 2013-09-29 SPOE   26.8 
#> 2 2013-09-29 OEVP   24.0 
#> 3 2013-09-29 FPOE   20.5 
#> 4 2013-09-29 GRUENE 12.4 
#> 5 2013-09-29 TS      5.73
#> 6 2013-09-29 NEOS    4.96
```

And to show this is what we want, let's plot the various parties over time:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(date, value, color = name)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 6634 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Allan could you explain better or share more information about the developer tool used in this case? Is the developer tool  the same from firefox and chrome? Sorry if my questions are too basics

Comment: @EveChanatasig yes, it's the same in both browsers. Hit F12 when in your browser to get the developer tools to appear. At the top of developer tools you will see a tab called Console. This should show you all the xhr calls that are made when you load a page. On firefox (which I use) there are some buttons in the top right of the console window which allow you to turn on and off various items. Just make sure XHR and Requests are selected.

Comment: It sounded very easy but i failed. Could you recommend webs or books where i can follow the process step by step?

Comment: You could try https://support.deskpro.com/en/kb/articles/how-to-inspect-ajax-requests-with-chrome-tools

Comment: It functioned very good. I tried with Chrome and the things were easier than Mozilla. Great hack! So, i have only one question. why request should be selected?