# Web scraping an interactive chart using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, charts, interactive

I'm new to web scraping and am trying to scrape the data from this interactive chart using R so that all the series are displayed in a single table: https://www.e61.in/spendtracker

I've used developer tools in chrome (inspect - network - fetch/XHR) but cannot find the data points.

Would be highly appreciative if someone can take a quick look and let me know a) if the data points are stored on the page somewhere b) if possible, explain how they identified the right file, and c) if it is a reasonably straightforward task to then generate a table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would if I knew what format the data was saved in! I am, first, seeking help about how to use the developer tool to identify what data I am able to scrape. As it stands I'm not sure if I am facing a question like this (using just jsonlite): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401465/is-it-possible-to-scrape-data-from-an-interactive-graph or like this (using rvest, stringr and jsonlite packages): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183783/how-to-scrape-data-from-chart-with-r

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from that iframe url -

before switching to R & rvest you should check the actual page source and perhaps run it though some beautifier. You'll see `Plotly.newPlot()` call, check how it gets array of those data series as a 2nd parameter. One option would be extracting that piece of javascript with regex, parse it as JSON and work from there.

Perhaps something like this:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

url <- "https://www-e61-in.filesusr.com/html/84f6c1_839cefc8bcc59c1cc688a6be6b4a5656.html"
html <- read_html(url)

# extract last <script> tag containing Plotly.newPlot() and dataseries'
plotly_js <- html %>% 
  html_element("script:last-of-type") %>% 
  html_text()

# extract array from js string, using \Q and \E to no escape all special chars
p_dataseries <- str_extract(plotly_js, '\\Q[{"connectgaps"\\E.*?\\Q"type":"scatter"}]\\E' )

# parse extracted string
ds_j <- fromJSON(p_dataseries,simplifyVector = FALSE)

# extract data, result will be in long format
df <- map_df(ds_j, `[`, c("name", "x", "y")) %>% 
  unnest(c(x,y)) %>%   
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(x)) 

str(df)
#> tibble [2,346 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ name: chr [1:2346] "Total" "Total" "Total" "Total" ...
#>  $ x   : chr [1:2346] "2020-01-12T00:00:00" "2020-01-19T00:00:00" "2020-01-26T00:00:00" "2020-02-02T00:00:00" ...
#>  $ y   : num [1:2346] 100 100.1 100.7 99.3 97.8 ...
#>  $ date: POSIXct[1:2346], format: "2020-01-12" "2020-01-19" ...
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   name  x                       y date               
#>   <chr> <chr>               <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1 Total 2020-01-12T00:00:00 100   2020-01-12 00:00:00
#> 2 Total 2020-01-19T00:00:00 100.  2020-01-19 00:00:00
#> 3 Total 2020-01-26T00:00:00 101.  2020-01-26 00:00:00
#> 4 Total 2020-02-02T00:00:00  99.3 2020-02-02 00:00:00
#> 5 Total 2020-02-09T00:00:00  97.8 2020-02-09 00:00:00
#> 6 Total 2020-02-16T00:00:00 100.  2020-02-16 00:00:00

p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = y, color = name)) +
  geom_path() +
  theme_minimal()
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oh wow you are amazing. Thanks! As I'm very keen to learn how to do this. How did you find this text: '\\Q[{"connectgaps"\\E.*?\\Q"type":"scatter"}]\\E' ?

Comment: It's a regular expression to match the relevant array in javascript, pattern starts with  a literal `[{"connectgaps"`, ends with `"type":"scatter"}]` ,   `.*?`in between  matches everything but as few times as possible, so it would not grab portion of following js array.  You can play with through  https://regex101.com/r/gHlg4h/1 .  Without \Q and \E all special characters in string (`[]{}":` ) must be explicitly escaped with `\ `  .

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to scrap the wrong URL - the one you've provided uses an iframe with the chart. You should take a deep look into the source code of this page instead (the iframe source): https://www-e61-in.filesusr.com/html/84f6c1_839cefc8bcc59c1cc688a6be6b4a5656.html

Comment: Thanks Bart! After some digging around it looks like it could be a document (https://www-e61-in.filesusr.com/html/84f6c1_839cefc8bcc59c1cc688a6be6b4a5656.html), a plotly javascript file (https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.12.1.min.js) or some sort of data image? I think its the first of these. I'm able to read this file in using the code:  url <- "https://www-e61-in.filesusr.com/html/84f6c1_839cefc8bcc59c1cc688a6be6b4a5656.html"
spendtracker <- read_html(url). But i'm a newcomer to web scraping and not sure what packages (or combination) to extract the underlying data. Any help appreciated!